# How to get rtcwake to use the right time to wake up?

Tags: debian, suspend

I need a way to wake up a Debian host every day at 11:45AM.

It looks like rtcwake is a good tool for this, but I can't get it to use the right time.

The hardware clock is set to UTC, and I'm located at UTC+2:

```
# timedatectl
      Local time: Tue 2017-03-28 01:19:45 CEST
  Universal time: Mon 2017-03-27 23:19:45 UTC
        RTC time: Mon 2017-03-27 23:19:46
       Time zone: Europe/Paris (CEST, +0200)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: yes
 Last DST change: DST began at
                  Sun 2017-03-26 01:59:59 CET
                  Sun 2017-03-26 03:00:00 CEST
 Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
                  Sun 2017-10-29 02:59:59 CEST
                  Sun 2017-10-29 02:00:00 CET
```

I tried nothing/l/u, to no avail:

```
# rtcwake -m no -t `date +%s -d"2017-03-28 11:45"`
```

→ 09:44:59

```
# rtcwake -m no -l -t $(date +\%s -d '2017-03-28 11:45')
```

→ 13:44:59

```
# rtcwake -m no -u -t $(date +\%s -d '2017-03-28 11:45')
```

→ 9:45:00

Is there something else I should update in the system to have rtcwake use the right time?

Thank you.

--
Edit:
Here's the output from cat /proc/driver/rtc:

```
rtc_time        : 00:08:06
rtc_date        : 2017-03-28
alrm_time       : 09:45:00
alrm_date       : 2017-03-28
alarm_IRQ       : no
alrm_pending    : no
update IRQ enabled      : no
periodic IRQ enabled    : no
periodic IRQ frequency  : 1024
max user IRQ frequency  : 64
24hr            : yes
periodic_IRQ    : no
update_IRQ      : no
HPET_emulated   : yes
BCD             : yes
DST_enable      : no
periodic_freq   : 1024
batt_status     : okay
```

BTW, Google didn't help to find how to cancel a job: "rtcwake -m disable" doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you actually test it? I mean: are you complaining because the displayed time is wrong, or because the machine does not actually wake up at the given time?

Comment: Not yet, but why does it not display the scheduled time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I see, `rtcwake` does use the right time. Apparently, the time that is displayed is the time of your RTC, not the time you set (local timezone). Therefore it is UTC-based when you tell `rtcwake` your RTC clock is set to UTC (with `-u` or `-a` the default). And it is the local time when you tell `rtcwake` your RTC clock is set to local time (with `-l`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But even if the BIOS is set to UTC, the user expects to see the actual wakeup time. No biggie,though.

Comment: As answered, `rtcwake` shows you the time it will wake up in UTC. But if you use `date` and you have your local time configured properly (as I can see from the timedatectl command this is good), your system will wake up at the specified local date time. So `rtcwake -m no -t $(date +%s -d"2017-03-28 11:45")` will shows `09:45` as this is CEST (so Summer time) and `rtcwake -m no -t $(date +%s -d"2017-02-28 11:45")` will shows `10:45` as this would be CET or Winter time (UTC+1).